# R: how to turn strings to arguments in order to be able to call a function?

Tags: r, shiny

I need to turn strings to arguments in order to be able to call a function.
Here is my data:

```
myfunction <- function(arg1=c('val1', 'val2'), arg2=c('val1', 'val2'){
  ...
}
```

The user will only supply one argument (arg1 or arg2) in the form of a string. Same is for the   values of this argument. 
For example, he may enter 'arg1' and the values as strings. The program will get those strings and have to supply them to the fonction myfunction (see bellow).

```
argument <- 'arg1'
values <- 'val1, val2, val3, val4, val5'
```

I tried:

```
myfunction(as.name(argument)=list(parse(text=values)))
```

But it did not work.

any idea how to make it work?

Thanks

**Edit**

As asked by Ananda Mahto, the argument name and its values came from a web application (using shiny) as input fields. 
As of the function I'm using it's not mine. So I cannot modify how it accepts the arguments. But, generally speaking, it uses those arguments and values to generate a plot.

Comment: Can you share your end goal? I don't quite follow what you're trying to do, what an example of the input would be, and so on....

Comment: I think you might just want the `...` argument.

Comment: I'm still unclear as to what you are trying to do but it seems like you should just write a wrapper function for myfunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way, assigning to an environment, which can be converted to a list with the correct attributes to use `do.call` (and getting `myfunction` to print its arguments):

```
tmp <- new.env()
assign(argument,unlist(strsplit(values,", ")),envir=tmp)
as.list(tmp)
$arg1
[1] "val1"  "val2" "val3" "val4" "val5"

do.call(myfunction,as.list(tmp))
[1] "val1" "val2" "val3" "val4" "val5"
[1] "val1" "val2"
```

Comment: Hmm - can't you avoid creating an environment?  `foo <- (strsplit(values,", "))
funcfoo<-function(x) print(x)`  then `do.call(funcfoo,foo)` appears to work the same way.  Did I miss something?

Comment: If you want to match variable by names you need to pass a named list to to `do.call`. Using the environment is one way of creating this, but there may be others.

Comment: Thank you James for the solution! It works fine for my case :-)